# Pass value of a variable from one loop to other Javascript and imacros

Tags: javascript, imacros

I want to download the photoos from a website using imacros. I need to change the name of each photo depending upon its product number. Here is my code:

```js
var macro;
macro = "CODE:";
macro += "SET !ERRORIGNORE YES" + "\n";
macro += "URL GOTO=mywebsite" + "\n";

macro += "TAG POS={{i}} TYPE=IMG ATTR=SRC:Text source" + "\n"; //page where i find the text
macro += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN FORM=NAME:form1 ATTR=ID:txt2ArtikelNr" + "\n";
macro += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=ID:txt2ArtikelNr EXTRACT=TXT" + "\n"; //This text I intend to use as image name
for (i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
  iimSet("i", i);
  iimPlay(macro);
  iimGetLastExtract(1);
  var inner;
  inner = "CODE:";
  inner += "SET !ERRORIGNORE YES" + "\n";
  inner += "FRAME NAME=Auswahlframe" + "\n";
    inner += "TAG POS={{j}} TYPE=IMG ATTR=SRC:image page" + "\n";
  inner += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG ATTR=SRC:image sourse" + "\n";
  inner += "ONDOWNLOAD FOLDER=* FILE=report_{{!Extract}}_image_{{!NOW:yyyymmdd_hhnnss}}.jpg WAIT=YES" + "\n"; // here I used the extracted text as image name
  inner += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG FORM=NAME:form1 ATTR=HREF:Image download address CONTENT=EVENT:SAVEITEM" + "\n";

  for (j = 1; j <= 15; j++) {
    iimSet("j", j);

    iimPlay(inner);

  }


}
```

The problem is that after iimPlay command, imacro deletes the stored (extracted)text. So my saved images do not have "product number" in their name.
Can somebody tell me how can I transfer the value of extracted text from one loop to second loop. Thx...

Comment: `... inner += "SET !EXTRACT " + iimGetLastExtract(1) + "\n"; ...`

Comment: Hello Shugar , I get #EANF# (Extraction Anchor Not Found)  error instead of image name. !!!

Comment: For testing purposes change your line in such way: `... iimPlay(macro);
  alert(iimGetLastExtract(1)); ...` and take a look at the result of extraction made in the first macro. (Only with several loops, not 100.)

Comment: Thank you very much ... My first Loop was not extracting the Text. Now it is working :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code instead as you can set variable inside string you want in your imacros code using iimSet() method

```js
var macro;
macro = "CODE:";
macro += "SET !ERRORIGNORE YES" + "\n";
macro += "URL GOTO=mywebsite" + "\n";

macro += "TAG POS={{i}} TYPE=IMG ATTR=SRC:Text source" + "\n"; //page where i find the text
macro += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN FORM=NAME:form1 ATTR=ID:txt2ArtikelNr" + "\n";
macro += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=ID:txt2ArtikelNr EXTRACT=TXT" + "\n"; //This text I intend to use as image name
for (i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
  iimSet("i", i);
  iimPlay(macro);
  var ExtractedTxt = iimGetLastExtract(1);
  var inner;
  inner = "CODE:";
  inner += "SET !ERRORIGNORE YES" + "\n";
  inner += "FRAME NAME=Auswahlframe" + "\n";
  inner += "TAG POS={{j}} TYPE=IMG ATTR=SRC:image page" + "\n";
  inner += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG ATTR=SRC:image sourse" + "\n";
  iimSet("ExtractedTxt", ExtractedTxt);
  inner += "ONDOWNLOADFOLDER=*FILE=report_{{ExtractedTxt}}_image_{{!NOW:yyyymmdd_hhnnss}}.jpg WAIT=YES" + "\n"; // here I used the extracted text as image name
  inner += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG FORM=NAME:form1 ATTR=HREF:Image download address CONTENT=EVENT:SAVEITEM" + "\n";

  for (j = 1; j <= 15; j++) {
    iimSet("j", j);

    iimPlay(inner);

  }


}
```

---edit-----
you can use ECMA6 syntax to set variable inside macro using multi line string called template literal like below:

```js
macro = `TAG POS=${i} TYPE=IMG ATTR=SRC:Text source`;// i is the variable assigned to macro
```

I used it in Firefox version +50